# Is the reduced scheme associated to a Cartier divisor always Cartier?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, divisors

Let $X$ be a normal integral variety over $\mathbb{C}$ and $D \subset X$ be a Cartier divisor in $X$. Is the associated reduced scheme $D_{\mathrm{red}}$ also necessarily a Cartier divisor in $X$?

Comment: No. Take for $X$ the quadric cone $xy+z^2=0$ in $\mathbb{C}^3$, and for $D$ the divisor $x=0$. Then $D$ is Cartier, but $D_{\operatorname{red}}$ is not.

Comment: This is true if $X$ is locally factorial (because any prime ideal of height one is principal in a UFD, see Th. 1.12A in Chap. I of Hartshorne).

Comment: @DamianRössler Thanks for the answer in the positive direction. abx: Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Consider, for instance, the quadratic cone
$$
X = \{xz - y^2 = 0\} \subset \mathbb{A}^3
$$
and the double line
$$
D = X \cap \{x = 0\} = \{x = y^2 = 0\}
$$
on $X$. Then $D$ is a Cartier divisor, but
$$
D_{\mathrm{red}} = \{x = y = 0\}
$$
is not Cartier (this is the simplest example of a Weil divisor which is not Cartier).